# Is it possible to have IE as a secondary browser on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer

I set up Google Chrome as my default browswer on Windows 8, but I have one web application I need to use (MLS data) that will only run on IE.  I see in Windows 8 where IE can be set as the "default browser" but that seems to be the only choice.  Can it be added as an icon just to be a secondary browser?  It sounds like from the discussions that it cannot.  I'm the opposite of a power user so any details you can provide are appreciated.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you asking if you can launch IE by manually?

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers are just applications. You can have IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera and others all installed on Windows 8. The default browser is just the one that is launched when links are clicked (say from emails) or HTML files are opened. You can launch IE from the desktop and navigate to the web application that requires it without effecting your default browser setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Internet Explorer in the Metro mode (or Modern UI, whichever sounds better to you) when it's not default browser, but you can still use it in the Desktop mode just by clicking its icon/tile.